# Adding a created date field from _id to all mongo documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to add a new field `createdDate` to all existing documents using `_id` field. I am doing this for easy readability of the documents. I tried following snippet but it is not working.

```
dbase.collection("cname").updateMany(
  {},
  { $set: { createdDate: new Date(parseInt("$_id".substring(0, 8), 16) * 1000) } } 
)
.then((resp)=>{ console.log('complete') })
```

This is the `createdDate` for all my documents now (after running the query): "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: `"$_id".substring(0, 8)` will result in "`$_id`", are you trying to read the id of the current document?

Comment: yes. createdDate of a document should be based on the current _id of that  document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html) to cast type to date from `_id`

```
dbase.collection("cname").updateMany(
  {},
  [{ 
    $set: { createdDate: { $toDate: "$_id" } } 
  }]
)
.then((resp) => { console.log('complete') });
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yddFjU4b1K6)